# How to pronounce "I ♥ Huckabees"?

Tags: title, i-heart-huckabees

**How are you supposed to pronounce the movie title "*I ♥ Huckabees*"?**

I have seen it written "I heart huckabees" but that might be because its hard to find and type the little ♥ character. This also would seem like an odd pronunciation (but then again its a strange title to begin with.)

Actual movie logo / title:

[image]

For instance, did the writer/director or some official publication ever clearly state how to say the title?

Comment: Heh. Was going to edit to include the movie tag but..  now I don't know what I'd have replaced the  with :)

Comment: Also notice the CMYK test pattern in the upper right. That is to aid the offset print shop, and it's normally on the part of the piece that is trimmed off.  It makes it look like an error.

Comment: @Jenayah And now the tag answers the question, which potentially makes the OP look silly to future viewers :-/

Comment: @Randal'Thor Only if you assume the strictly governed 27-character alphabet of SE tags is the nonplusultra reference for pronounciation of not only English words and emoticons, but individual works of art and proprietary trademarks. Afterall, even the question itself recognizes this as a possible compromise already, while still finding the courage to articulate this question. ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It’s pronounced “heart” usually but “love” is accepted. From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Heart_Huckabees):

> I ♥ Huckabees (known usually as I Heart Huckabees but also as I Love Huckabees) is a 2004 American comedy film directed and produced by David O. Russell, who co-wrote the screenplay with Jeff Baena.

Both Wikipedia and [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0356721/) refer to it as *I Heart Huckabees*.

In an [interview with Indie Wire](https://www.indiewire.com/2013/11/afi-david-o-russell-talks-immediacy-of-film-says-i-heart-huckabees-is-his-least-favorite-movie-more-91774/), the writer/director David O. Russell is quoted as saying:

> However, another short that Russell was planning was stuck in the writing stages. “I wanted to make a short film, that later became ‘I Heart Huckabees,’ about a guy who sits in the back of a Chinese restaurant with microphones on every table to surreptitiously listen to everybody’s conversations, then write perversely personal fortunes for each of the people.

So, he uses "heart" himself.

As to the oddness of the phrase, it's actually pretty common to see around now. There's a few company names based on it, even. The most recognizable is probably iHeartRadio, a music streaming service.

Comment: Neat observation about the use of "heart" like that, as a verb... I wonder if that is an effect of the film or perhaps some other usage was an influence for it.

Comment: @DaveInCaz The original is [I ♥ New York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Love_New_York), which predates the film by about 27 years. That Wikipedia article explicitly mentions *I ♥ Huckabees* as one of the many, many names inspired by the New York slogan.

Comment: The one issue with that, @BrianMcCutchon , is that the slogan is "I love New York" (according to that Wikipedia article) and references "heart" as a facetious usage - probably not inappropriate in this case.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon as a native NY'er I'm familiar with that one! :)  Hadn't thought of it. There even was an "I love New York" jingle which is quite recognizable!

Comment: The slogan uses the word "love", but it's usually written with the heart symbol. The facetious pronunciation caught on and became a "thing", and the filmmaker adopted it.